# C# Динамическая загрузка списка, нулевое значение

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

Нулевое значение id_ в контроллере.

```
public ActionResult GetItems(string id_)
{
     throw new Exception();
}
```

Представление.

```
$(function () {
        $('#state').change(function()
        {
            var id = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetItems", "Specialization")/' + id,
                success: function (data) {
                    // заменяем содержимое присланным частичным представлением
                }
            });
        });
    })
```

Создание роута.

```
  endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                   name: "2",
                   pattern: "{controller=Specialization}/{action=GetItems}/{id?}",
                   defaults: new { controller = "Specialization", action = "GetItems"});
```

Помогите разобраться в чем ошибка, заранее спасибо.

Comment: Нажимаем F12 в браузере, переходим на вкладку network, смотрим какой запрос уезжает на сервер.

Comment: И что это за подчеркивание в имени переменной? `string id_`?

Comment: id_ имя переменной.
Сам запрос строится нормально.
Request URL: https: // localhost: 44358 / Specialization / GetItems / 1

Comment: Зачем в имени переменной знак `_`?

Comment: Незнаю почему, но без этого знака **_** оно заработало. Благодарю Вас.

Comment: Очень просто, потому что у вас нет этого знака в вашем маршруте `"controller=Specialization}/{action=GetItems}/{id?}",`